# If $F \leq\overline{\mathbb{Q}}(x)$ then either $F/\mathbb{Q}$ or $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}(x)/F$ is algebraic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, transcendental-numbers

> Suppose that $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$, and let $F \leq \overline{\mathbb{Q}}(x)$ be a subfield. Then I want to show that either $F/\mathbb{Q}$ or $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}(x)/F$ is an algebraic extension.

I guess I get the idea somewhat- If $F/\mathbb{Q}$ is not algebraic then that must mean that in some form $F = K(x)$ where $K \leq \mathbb{Q}$, and then obviously we do get that $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}(x)/K(x)$ is algebraic. That is the intuitive answer, but how does one formalize this?

If $F/\mathbb{Q}$ is not algebraic, then there is $y \in F \subseteq \overline{\mathbb{Q}}(x)$ that is transcendental. Does this directly imply that $x \in F$? I'm sort of confused here. And if we do get that $x \in F$, we get that $F \geq \mathbb{Q}(x)$, but can one say that $F = K(x)$ for some $K \geq \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: You should consider where $F=\Bbb Q(i,x^2)$ fits in your speculation.

Comment: So my argument basically fails then by using your example. Actually given your $F$ I'm not even sure how one sees that $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}(x)/F$ is algebraic.

Comment: Well, $x$ is a root of the polynomial $T^2-x^2\in F[T]$.

Comment: Ah yes of course. Silly me. 


So I understand you're saying that $F$ instead would be of the form $F = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1, \cdots, \alpha_k, \beta_1, \cdots, \beta_n)$ where the $\alpha_i$ are algebraic elements and the $\beta_i$ are of the form $x^p$ (and from which we can easily obtain algebraicity. That makes sense and was probably what I should have seen from the beginning. How can one deduce this structure for $F$? I think this primarily involves deducing the forms of the $\beta_i$

Comment: I've never said that $F$ should be finitely generated, in point of fact it can be false. Also: if I try to consider $F=\Bbb Q\left(\frac{x^3+9x^2+5}{x^7-\alpha x^4+1}\right)$, where $\alpha$ is the root of $x^9+17x+3$ with positive imaginary part and largest real part, does the police come to get me?

Comment: Hmm, well now I'm just not sure then.

Comment: Hmm I hope I'm not overcomplicating this- is it as easy as saying, if $F/\mathbb{Q}$ is not algebraic, then $F > \bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ and then there will be some $x^k \in F\setminus \bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ and thus $x$ is algebraic over $F$ as the solution to $T^k - x^k$ and thus $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}(x)/F$ is algebraic?

Comment: @Saitama: If $F/\Bbb Q$ is not algebraic, then $F$ contains something outside $\bar{\Bbb Q}$, yes but you cannot say $F > \bar{\Bbb Q}$. Moreover, why is there some $x^k$ in $F$? For example, if $F = \Bbb Q\left(\frac{1}{x^2 + 1}\right)$, then what $x^k$ do you have?

Comment: Could you give a hint haha. I'm not sure if I'm just looking in the completely wrong direction or what

Comment: @AryamanMaithani Well, in $\Bbb Q((x^2+1)^{-1})$ you have $x^2=\frac1{(x^2+1)^{-1}}-1$.

Answer (score 3):

Your idea that if $F$ is not algebraic over $\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}$ then it must be of the form $F = K(x)$ is not right, but something very similar does work.

If $F$ is not algebraic over $\Q$, then we must have one element in $F$ which is transcendental over $\Q$. Let's call this element $t \in \newcommand{\QQ}{\overline{\Q}}\QQ(x)$. Set $K = \Q(t)$. Clearly, $\Q \leq K \leq F \leq \QQ(x)$ where $A \leq B$ represents $B$ is an extension field of $A$.

It is clear that if $\QQ(x)$ is algebraic over $K$, then it is algebraic over $F$, so without loss of generality, we assume that $F = \Q(t)$ for some element $t \in \QQ(x)$.

Now, what does it mean for $t$ to be an element of $\QQ(x)$? One has that
$$t = \frac{p(x)}{q(x)},$$
where $p,q \in \QQ[x]$. Can you use this create a non-zero polynomial with coefficients in $F = \Q(t)$ such that $x$ is a root of it?

In other words, can you describe a polynomial $f(X) \in F[X] = \Q(t)[X]$ such that $f(x) = 0$ and $f \not\equiv 0$?

Comment: Is there actually some simple polynomial that you have in mind? For example, if $q(x)$ were $1$, then $f(X) = p(X) - t \in \bar{\Bbb Q}(t)[X]$ would have shown that $x$ is alg. over $\bar{\Bbb Q}(t)$. Since everything in $\Bbb Q$ is alg. over $F$, we are done. But for a rational function, it doesn't seem so easy. For example, we can't take something like $p(X)/q(x) - t$ since $q(x)$ isn't a priori in $\bar{\Bbb Q}(t)$.

Comment: @hello: Whoof, there's a subtlety here that I missed. The polynomial I was going for is $f(X) = t q(X) - p(X)$. It's clearly that $f(x) = 0$, and it's clear this polynomial is non-zero since it has degree $1$ in $t$. But this is a polynomial in $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}(t)[X]$, not $\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}\Q(t)[X]$. The argument is still fixable, since this shows that $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}(x)$ is algebraic over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}(t)$ while $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}(t)$ is obviously algebraic over $\Q(t)$.